# Javascript Regex - get variable from sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I want create simple AI for youtube in javascript. I want to write into input string like "Find Pranks on youtube". And that word "Prank" is variable... Everyone can write whatever thay want,but it must be sentence "Find 'something' on youtube". I tried to create regex, but it's to hard for me. Is it posible to do this like that?

The regex I tried is:  `\\Find\s\[abc]\s\\on\\youtube/i;`

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="uq" class="input auto-size"/>
<button id="button" onclick="question();" class="button" href="javascript:;">Ask</button>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function question()
    const findonyoutube = /(?<=find)(.*)(?=on youtube)/gm;
    var str = document.getElementById('uq').value;
    if(findonyoutube.test(str))
    {
    alert(findonyoutube.exec(str)[0]);
    }
}
```

Not working, it return `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`

Comment: What does this have to do with AI?

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool for writing an AI.  Or maybe you aren't actually writing an artificial intelligence?  It certainly looks like a very basic regex right now with a single grouping construct.  You tried?  Please show us your attempts.

Comment: Here is regex for extracting everything in between `Find` and `on youtube`. `(?<=Find)(.*)(?=on youtube)`. It uses `positive lookbehind` and `positive lookahead`

Comment: @Amy In this phase, it isn't AI, but i want to try it and this is good for start. In future, i can with this play specific video by voice. My regex was `\\Find\s\[abc]\s\\on\\youtube/i;`but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture anything in between two words you can use:

---

```js
function getVariable() {
  const regex = /(?<=Find)(.*)(?=on youtube)/i;
  let input = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  let match = regex.exec(input);
  if(match) {
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = match[0];
    return match;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }  
}
```

```html
<h4>Example: Find ponies on youtube</h4>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<button onclick="getVariable();">Get Variable</button>
<br><br><hr>
<h3 id="debug"></h3>
```

---

It uses a [`positive lookahead and lookbehind`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve this.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  He wants to extract the word following "Find" and before "on youtube", not insert a word.

Comment: Like actually regex match the variable in between `Find` and `on youtube` ?

Comment: Yes, that is what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Amy, yes you are right. Thats exactly what I want.

Comment: @Alex I tried this code and it's works, but it when i put document.getElementById("input").value instead of string, it stopped working.

Comment: Give me a minute.

Comment: @Expertik It would be helpful if you demonstrated this with a complete example in the question.  We can't guess what, specifically, you've done incorrectly.

Comment: `const findonyoutube = /(?<=find)(.*)(?=on youtube)/gm;
  var str = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if(findonyoutube.test(str))
  {
  alert(findonyoutube.exec(str)[0]);
  }
`

Comment: Edit your question.  Code in comments is very difficult to read and work with.  Also, your example needs to be [mcve].  The code in your comment may or may not work depending on where in your file that code resides.  Context matters.  You also don't mention what error, if any, you are getting.

Comment: @Alex Yes it's nice, but i need to solve, if user write another sentence without thats words. Because, if i write here only hello, it returns same error code as in my code.

Comment: Reword your question. You mean words like "find", "look", "search", you need a word dictionary for that. There is no simple regex I can think of that will find whatever you want in a robust way.

Comment: @Alex I don't want that, but i need only fix error... If I write "Find dogs on youtube", it works fine, but if I write "Hello world", there is error. And i want to supress this error.

Comment: @Alex Sorry for that, but that code is important for me... And thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Done. Have a look.

Comment: @Alex Yes, that's perfect! Thanks you very much.

Comment: Make sure to rate best answer. ;)